# Postman failing to connect to Dockerized .Net 3.1 WebAPI

Tags: docker, docker-compose, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Dockerized .Net Core 3.1 WebApi that was connecting successfully to a dockerized MySql instance. This has been working perfectly until I made some changes to the API. I have since reverted the changes , ran docker-compose up with a new image but whenever I run to requests to the API from Postman I get connection error (even to the default **Weather** endpoint). I can however connect to the MySql docker instance:

[image: POSTMAN]

As a check I have **added a new WebApi project** (with no additional logic) dockerized it and run docker-compose up but I still get same error when I run a simple GET to the default Weather endpoint.

It appears as if something **has suddenly broken** either at the Docker end or my .Net Core end because this was working perfectly before. I have tried docker inspect  and a Postman request to http://172.17.0.4:5070/weatherforecast but I still get same connection error.

Checking Postman Proxy settings yields nothing (the Proxy tab is actually absent in the console). Both WebAPIs yield responses perfectly when I run them from Visual Studio but as soon as I Dockerize Postman cannot connect. Running the request from Fiddler yields Status Code 504.

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5070
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ChatAPI.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'
services:
 chatapi:
build: .
ports: 
  - "5070:5000"
```

Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();          
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

What am I missing that could have possibly changed ? Any pointers on debugging the container/Docker to get more information about why I suddenly connect.
I would expect to be able to get more descriptive logs or tracing or live inspection because to me for now it appears like a black-box :

[image: CHATAPI]

Comment: your dockerfile is wrong... you see you are forwarding port 5070 to port 5000 which is inside the container... but the api inside container is listening on port 5070.  So you have two options... 1 change the docker compose to be "5070:5070" or change your docker file to be ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000

Comment: in a way think about a docker container as a separate "machine" so when you do this in docker compose "5070:5000" you are actually saying: "forward all traffic coming in port 5070 of the host machine to the port 5000 of the container".  On the other hand  ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000  means that "inside" your container you will listen on port 5000....

Answer (score 1):

Change your docker-compose file to following:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
 chatapi:
build: .
ports: 
  - "5070:5070" //This is your issue
```

or change the docker file to the following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000 // YOUR PROBLEM WAS HERE
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ChatAPI.dll"]
```